# Deactivate WordPress Plugin if URL is

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed SMS Validator so everyone who register to my site must enter there phone number to sign-up

Now I have created a new function (link) to add a different type user role if users sign-up by visit this link:
http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&role=vip_member

I want to turn OFF SMS Validator ONLY for this URL link.

Is it possible to do it somehow?

---

Success so far using mathielo code:

```
// Activate SMSGlobal 
function activate_plugin_conditional() {
if ( !is_plugin_active('sms-validator-SMSG/sms-validator.php') ) {
    activate_plugins('sms-validator-SMSG/sms-validator.php');
    }
}

// Deactivate SMSGlobal
function deactivate_plugin_conditional() {
if ( is_plugin_active('sms-validator-SMSG/sms-validator.php') ) {
    deactivate_plugins('sms-validator-SMSG/sms-validator.php');
    }
}

// Now you in fact deactivate the plugin if the current URL matches your desired URL
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/wp-login.php?action=register&role=vip_member') !== FALSE){
// Calls the disable function at WP's init
    add_action( 'init', 'deactivate_plugin_conditional' );
}

if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/wp-login.php?action=register&role=seller') !== FALSE){
// Calls the enable function at WP's init
    add_action( 'init', 'activate_plugin_conditional' );
}

if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/wp-login.php?action=register&role=provider') !== FALSE){
// Calls the enable function at WP's init
    add_action( 'init', 'activate_plugin_conditional' );
}
```

So far this code helps me to activate and deactivate this plugin in this 3 selected URLs.
But I want this plugin to be activated if is deactivated in this links: **/wp-login.php** and **/wp-login.php?action=register**

But if I set it to activate on URL: /wp-login.php then it will not be deactivated on URL: /wp-login.php?action=register&role=vip_member where I need it to be deactivated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the current URL using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and then disable the plugin in `functions.php`:

```
// Just creating the function that will deactivate the plugin
function deactivate_plugin_conditional() {
    if ( is_plugin_active('plugin-folder/plugin-name.php') ) {
        deactivate_plugins('plugin-folder/plugin-name.php');    
    }
}

// Now you in fact deactivate the plugin if the current URL matches your desired URL
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'my-disable-url') !== FALSE){
    // Calls the disable function at WP's init
    add_action( 'init', 'deactivate_plugin_conditional' );
}
```

**Note:** Be aware that php's `strpos()` may return `0` if the needle matches the given string at position zero, so the condiional `!==` is needed.

Got my references from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12163/disable-plugin-plugin-action-via-theme) and implemented the URL check. Check out the current value of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` at your desired URL for a perfect match.

---

**Answering the second part of your question:**

You could improve your code removing the last 2 `if`s and complementing the first one with an `else`, like so:

```
// Now you in fact deactivate the plugin if the current URL matches your desired URL
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/wp-login.php?action=register&role=vip_member') !== FALSE){
    // Calls the disable function at WP's init
    add_action( 'init', 'deactivate_plugin_conditional' );
}
// Otherwise, for any other URLs the plugin is activated if it's currently disabled.
else{
    add_action( 'init', 'activate_plugin_conditional' );
}
```

Now for *every* URL that is not the one you wish to deactivate the plugin, your code will enable the plugin if it is currently inactive.

Comment: Hi mathielo, this code works great to Disable this plugin as I wanted. But unfortunately it Disables the plugin for other page where I want it to have it activated. I tried to reverse your code for my other URL but did not success. Can you please provide me a example of how to activate a plugin if URL is?

Comment: Please post both URLs and specify in which one you'd like to disable the plugin. I'll take a look :)

Comment: I have followed your advice and made a code. Please have a look on my edited question. I believe this code can be shorten or improved.

Comment: @Cyborg just edited my answer, I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Cyborg please consider checking this answer as a solution if it worked for you.

Comment: this solution is good. But there are still 1 problem. This plugin is NOT deactivated when you visit /wp-login.php?action=register&role=vip_member. But if you visit this link and then refresh this link then the plugin is deactivated. The good think is the plugin is activated on all other links at first visit (don't need refresh.) I wonder is it there any way to refresh this page once when visited? Or preload this this page by GET og cURL or someother way before the visitor actually are sent to this link?

Comment: @Cyborg take a look at [WP Action Hooks Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Maybe all you need is to use an action hook that is triggered before the `init` hook. Try using [`muplugins_loaded`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded). I can't say for sure, but it looks like it could solve this problem without the need of a raw page refresh.